# Insert SQL from combobox/textbox selections

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to add a row of data into the table using the selections from comboboxes and the textlabel. The error I'm receiving is in regard to the insert statement. Is this the correct way to reference the values in a combobox or textbox? I'm inserting into a table that has an autonumber primary key. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub addResult_Click()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "INSERT INTO Results (Student_ID, Class_ID, Test_Type, Student_Score, Total_Score, Level)
VALUES ('" & Me.cboStudents.Column(0) & "',
'" & Me.cboTeacher.Column(0) & "', 
'" & Me.cboTestType.Column(1) & "', 
'" & Me.txtTotalScore.Value & "', 
'" & Me.txtStudentScore.Value & "', 
'" & Me.cboTeacher.Column(2) & "')"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: Try doing `MsgBox strSQL` to see what the raw query string is.  It looks like perhaps there is no space before `VALUES`, which would explain why it's not executing.

Comment: What does the error say, specifically?

Comment: I would guess that you are getting a `Type Mismatch` error.  Surround String values with single quotes `'`, Date values with hashes `#` and do not surround Numeric values with anything.

Comment: When posting you should always add the error number and description.  The easiest way to get these is to click `Debug` on the error message box, open the `Immediate Window` type `?Err.Number,Err.Description` and press enter.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for the comment. The error number is 438 and the message is "Object doesn't support this property or method". New to VBA, appreciate your help.